# I can not see advertiser (multipeer connectivity) in my list, why?

Tags: multipeer-connectivity

I could not see advertiser in my list. I run this code on device and simulator, do you know why?

[image]

Here is all the code added to the main viewcontroller. I am using [nshipser multipeer connectivity](http://nshipster.com/multipeer-connectivity/) tutorial:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    static NSString * const XXServiceType = @"xx-service";
    localPeerID = [[MCPeerID alloc] initWithDisplayName:[[UIDevice currentDevice] name]];

    MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser *advertiser =
    [[MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser alloc] initWithPeer:localPeerID
                                      discoveryInfo:nil
                                        serviceType:XXServiceType];
    advertiser.delegate = self;
    [advertiser startAdvertisingPeer];

    MCSession *session = [[MCSession alloc] initWithPeer:localPeerID
                                        securityIdentity:nil
                                    encryptionPreference:MCEncryptionNone];
    session.delegate = self;

    MCNearbyServiceBrowser *browser = [[MCNearbyServiceBrowser alloc] initWithPeer:localPeerID serviceType:XXServiceType];
    browser.delegate = self;

    MCBrowserViewController *browserViewController =
    [[MCBrowserViewController alloc] initWithBrowser:browser
                                             session:session];
    browserViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    browserViewController.delegate = self;

    self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;

    [self presentViewController:browserViewController animated:YES completion:
     ^{
         [browser startBrowsingForPeers];
     }];
}

- (void)advertiser:(MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser *)advertiser didReceiveInvitationFromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID withContext:(NSData *)context invitationHandler:(void(^)(BOOL accept, MCSession *session))invitationHandler
{
    UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"didReceiveInvitationFromPeer get called" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [av show];

    if ([self.mutableBlockedPeers containsObject:peerID]) {
        invitationHandler(NO, nil);
        return;
    }

    [self.mutableBlockedPeers addObject:peerID];


    MCSession *session = [[MCSession alloc] initWithPeer:localPeerID
                                        securityIdentity:nil
                                    encryptionPreference:MCEncryptionNone];
    session.delegate = self;

    invitationHandler(YES, session);
}
```

Comment: Do you get invitations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two main problems you have with the code.

The first is that you don't have any strong references to your advertiser, so as soon as viewDidAppear finishes, it will be deallocated (and thus advertising stops).

So, make sure you add a property to your view controller and store the advertiser in it:

```
@interface ViewController()<MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate, etc>
@property(nonatomic, strong) MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser *advertiser;
@end

...

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    ... create the advertiser, etc
    self.advertiser = advertiser
    ... etc
}
```

The second problem arises from your creation and use of the browser object.

From Apple's documentation of the `MCBrowserViewController` class:

> Important: If you want the browser view controller to manage the browsing process, the browser object must not be actively browsing, and its delegate must be nil.

So, delete the line that says `browser.delegate = self` *and also* delete the code block containing `[browser startBrowsingForPeers]` (pass nil instead) as the browser view controller does this for you.

Alternatively, don't even create a browser object directly but let the browser view controller do it instead, by using the other init method:

```
MCBrowserViewController *browserViewController = [[MCBrowserViewController alloc] initWithServiceType:XXServiceType session:session];
```

Comment: I am having the same issue (peers are never found). I added the strong reference to the advertiser. I was already using `-[MCBrowserViewController initWithServiceType:session:]`. What else can be happening?

Comment: Oh, forget it... I was trying to mutually discover an iPhone and the simulator on a Mac, but only the iPhone was connected to the WiFi network (the Mac was on Ethernet)!! Now is seems to work.